# Run multiple lines at the same time bash

Tags: bash, fastq

So I'm working on a script in a cluster and i need to run this:

```
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f ITS_C1-5_rRNA.fq -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f ITS_C3-2_rRNA.fq -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f ITS_C3-3_rRNA.fq -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f ITS_C3-5_rRNA.fq -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f ITS_C4-5_rRNA.fq -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f ITS_C5-1_rRNA.fq -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f ITS_C5-4_rRNA.fq -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual
convert_fastaqual_fastq.py -f ITS_C5-5_rRNA.fq -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual
```

As you can see, each line is different and each line takes like 2 days to run.
The command what it does is transform a sample into two different formats but does it from sample to sample.
What I want is that when I run the script all the samples run at the same time, simultaneously.

An unsightly solution would be to generate a file for each sample and run it one at a time on separate CPUs in the cluster. I want a single job running at the same time in parallel.

Thanks!

Comment: You can spawn different processes. Appending `&` at the end of each line should be the way to go. If you want to keep track of logs of each instance you should look at `nohup` utility.

Comment: should I add a "wait" at the end?

Comment: consult the author of a full blown answer below. Personally I see no need in `wait` but I may miss something.

Comment: @ddnomad I was under the impression it was important that the resulting script not exit until the jobs are done or had failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to start each job in the background and then wait for all of them. The pattern `ITS_C?-?_rRNA.fq` will match each of the jobs that you've specified.

```
i=0
for file in ITS_C?-?_rRNA.fq; do
    convert_fastaqual_fastq.py \
        -f "$file" -c fastq_q_to_fastaqual \
        1>> job"$i".out \
        2>> job"$i".err &
    ((i++))
done

wait
```

If you want more information about which jobs failed, you can do something like this instead of `wait` (note that this requires you to keep track of which pid is associated with which file)

```
for job in $(jobs -p); do
    if wait "$job"; then
        printf "job %s succeeded\n" "$job"
    else
        printf "job %s failed\n" "$job"
    fi
done
```